# How to reference a class that is not defined yet?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following two classes:

```
class Product(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'product'

    ProductID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    StartOperatorID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.UserID'), nullable=False)
    StartOperator = db.relationship("User", foreign_keys=[StartOperatorID])
    WorkBenchID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('workbench.WorkBenchID'))
    WorkBench = db.relationship(WorkBench)


class WorkBench(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'workbench'

    WorkBenchID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

However, I get the following NameError, since WorkBench is defined below Product:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-3a482de7fdcf> in <module>()
----> 1 from example import models

/home/Sin5k4/example/models.py in <module>()
     16 
---> 17 class Product(db.Model):
     18     ProductID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

/home/Sin5k4/example/models.py in Product()
     21     WorkBenchID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('workbench.WorkBenchID'))
---> 22     WorkBench = db.relationship(WorkBench)
     23 

NameError: name 'WorkBench' is not defined
```

Coming from a .NET background, I'm really struggling with this.  What is the correct way to define a relationship to this class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a Python program is interpreted, the class definitions are executed in order, including the definition of class level variables (such as that relationship). To allow out-of-order definitions of relationships, SQLAlchemy has some other semantics besides passing the class directly. In fact, some of your other relationships are already using this form: pass the string name rather than the class object. You can also pass a lambda that evaluates to the class object, either will fix this.

```
# by class name (preferred in most cases)
WorkBench = db.relationship('WorkBench')
# or by lambda
WorkBench = db.relationship(lambda: WorkBench)
```